# Make git interactive rebase say "p" instead of "pick"?

Tags: git

This is a minor annoyance. When I do `git rebase -i origin/master`, it says "pick" and I have to press backspace 4 times to delete it and change it to something else (or learn a keyboard shortcut). Is there a way to make it just say "p"? I'm using a git alias for rebasing, so I can just add it there.

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't do that, but if you're using the default vim editor `dw` will delete the whole word in only two keystrokes.

Comment: …and `cw` replace (change) the word…

Answer (score 2):

Since git 2.16 a few months after this question was asked, there's config option `rebase.abbreviateCommands` for this.

`$ git config --global rebase.abbreviateCommands true`

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using an alias for the rebase, you could include this line:

```
sed -i -e '2,$ s/^pick/p/' .git/rebase-merge/git-rebase-todo
```

This command will change all lines that start with "pick" to "p" in the file that you modify during the interactive rebase.

This may require some playing around with/timing but could be a starting point for your desired functionality.